# React Native, Redux store after minimize

Tags: android, react-native, redux

I am making a react-native app that is also making use of redux. 
I recently realised that the redux store state is lost every time the app is minimized. After minimizing the state contains map keys for my reducers, but no values inside. I am 'quite' confident that this is new behaviour, as some code that was working is now broken, but all my dependency versions are set to specific numbers..

I know I can use something like redux-storage to persist the state, but should this be necessary?

Is it expected that the store state is lost when minimizing the app?

Currently only developing on Android, will be doing an iOS version in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the dev mode. When having debug off and loading js bundle instead of via network, the problem goes away.